# jQuery Isotope items overlapping onLoad in IE8 - defined width list items, not images

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jquery-isotope

The issue with Isotope's overlapping items is well documented, but it seems everyone else is just using images and their problem is solved by using `$(window).load(function(){ ..... });` or the `imagesLoaded` plugin.

I am finding that all browsers work fine except for IE8 where I experience the overlapping.
This problem is only `onload`; if I click any of the filters the style is correct.  But I've tried wrapping my script in `$(window).load(function(){ ..... });` and it doesn't work!

[image: Overlapping in IE8]

When I use the IE inspector, it appears as though the width that Isotope is calculating is 80px off in IE8.

These are in a `<ul>` and the `<li>`'s have a defined with of 349px.  In Chrome, when I use the inspector I can see that it adds the correct width of 379px (this is the 349px width + 30px left margin) in the inline styles on the `<li>` element:

`position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(379px, 0px, 0px);`

In IE8, however, it adds the following inline style:

`left: 299px; top: 0px; position: absolute;`

**Other CSS details:**

- The margin to the left of each item is **30px**
- The container `<ul>` has a negative margin of **-30px** to level up the grid
- The padding is set on an element inside the `<li>` and is **20px**
- The image has a width of 75px defined

I can't work out why it's overlapping by that 80px or how to stop it! Driving me insane.

Any help?  I wanted to write a fiddle to show this but struggled with jsfiddle and IE8, even with the jsfiddle.net/draft/.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this tumbleweed question, I ended up having to resolve this using % widths on items as the media query I had was causing the issue.

In actual fact, the media query issue only seemed to happen in IE8 so I targetted that browser specifically with styles that used % widths.

Comment: Interesting.. running into something similar.. I wonder if it has something to do with IE8 not having media queries..  I'm using respond.js and all the items just sit in the top left of their parent

Comment: but.. I am using percentages for widths already, so thaaat's not it.

Comment: I was using respond.js as well.  I can't remember exactly how I set this up as it was a while ago. Presumably your respond.js comes before your isotope script?

Comment: yup. i figured the issue was because i'm using a trick to create responsive squares where you have height:0 and padding-bottom:100%. isotope wasn't able to handle that in IE8